# Why do the div elements overlay here?

Tags: html, css, mozilla

I am about that page: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Mozilla/Connect

There is a yellow block with text **"This translation incomplete Please help us to translate ..."** and below a block 'article' which overlays with it.

I can't find out why this happens.

There is no absolute positioning. The below (article) block has position relative but no margins.

I am curious why it is happening. I played around in firebug with css properties and nothing helps.

Comment: Tried to set `display:block;` to that element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting

```
.dev-program-first {
   margin-top: -60px;
}
```

in `Connect$styles`, line 80.

That affects the three boxes below to overlay the translation message. Setting it to `0`, it looked fine for me. Such overlaying is often caused by negative margins, so you should avoid them if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to force the warning message on top by altering it's z-index.
Of course, you need to set it as a relative positions as well.

```
.warning warning-review 
{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 999999;
}
```

If that is what you are after. If the question is why the boxes aren't placed underneath the warning on the y axies, @ConcurrentHashMap is spot on.